# Function of a Poisson Point Process

Tags: probability

Let $(P_s)$ be a Poisson point process on a state space $X$ with intensity measure $\mu$. Let $f(s,x)$ be a non-negative integer valued function on $[0,1]\times X$. Let $N = \sum_{s\leq 1} \mathbb 1_{P_s \not=\Delta} f(s,P_s)$, where here $P_s = \Delta$ (the "graveyard point") if $P_s$ is not an element of $X$, i.e. $s$ is not a jump time for $P$. For example, we might have a family of sets $A_s \subset X$ and $f(s,x) = \mathbb 1_{x \in A_s}$. What assumptions on $f$ are needed for $N$ to have a Poisson distribution?

I tried to compute the characteristic functional of $N$. I also tried looking at the process $N_t = \sum_{s\leq t} \mathbb 1_{P_s \not=\Delta} f(s,P_s)$, which has independent increments, and using some sort of general result about such processes. Neither of these approaches were successful, however. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Presumably $f$ is nonnegative and integer-valued?

Comment: Yeah, $f$ is required to be integer valued. I corrected the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is nonnegative integer-valued, $N=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}nN_n$, where $N_n=\sum\limits_{0\leqslant s\leqslant 1}\mathbf 1_{f(s,P_s)=n}$. Each random variable $N_n$ has a Poisson distribution with parameter
$$
\lambda_n=\int_0^1\int_X\mathbf 1_{f(s,x)=n}\mu(\mathrm dx)\mathrm ds,
$$
with the convention that $N_n=0$ almost surely if $\lambda_n=0$, and the sequence $(N_n)$ is independent since the sets $\{(s,x)\in[0,1]\times X\mid f(s,x)=n\}$ are disjoint. Thus,
$$
E[s^N]=\prod_{n\geqslant1}E[(s^n)^{N_n}]=\exp\left(-\sum_{n\geqslant1}\lambda_n(1-s^n)\right).
$$
This shows that the distribution of $N$ is Poisson if and only if $\lambda_n=0$ for every $n\geqslant2$, that is, $\mu(\{x\in X\mid f(s,x)\geqslant2\})=0$, $\mathrm ds$-almost everywhere, or equivalently,
$$
\int_0^1\mu(\{x\in X\mid f(s,x)\geqslant2\})\mathrm ds=0.
$$